# Pass in parent form to ShowDialog that is called from a class instance

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I have a form.

In that form I create an instance of a class on a new thread because it runs some long running logic. The form also gives the user the ability to cancel this logic/thread.

That class opens a new form if input is required.

The new form sometimes appears behind the other form.

I set a property on the class:

```
public Form ParentForm{get;set;}
```

I can now do:

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.ShowDialog(ParentForm);
```

However I get a cross thread exception when calling `ShowDialog(ParentForm)`.

I know I can use `InvokeRequired` somehow but not sure how on a property.

Thanks

**UPDATE: Have tried doing this but still get exception:**

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.ShowDialog(GetParentForm()); 



private Form GetParentForm()
{
    //You have to Invoke() so you can wait for the function to return and obtain its return value.
    if (ParentForm.InvokeRequired)
    {
        return (Form)ParentForm.Invoke(new Func<Form>(() => GetParentForm()));
    }
    else
    {
        return ParentForm;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Winforms flubs this check and that can be worked around, but the problem is indicative of a greater issue.  You are shoving a dialog when the user is working with a window on your main thread.  When she doesn't expect it.  Odds are high that she'll accidentally close the dialog with a mouse click or key press that was intended for the main window.  She'll never even see the dialog.  Fix *that* problem first and you won't have this problem either.

Comment: @HansPassant The user is expecting it. They click a button that starts the thread and they have a loading gif to show the task is running and know to wait for it to return or interact with any popup that may appear

Comment: Well, then just display it on the UI thread.  Use Control.BeginInvoke()

Comment: How do I call the showMyNewForm from my separate class on a different thread and test its ModalResult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated method (`GetParentForm`) won't work because you're wrapping the task of getting the reference to `ParentForm` in an `InvokeRequired` block. You could try wrapping the `ShowDialog` call in such a block instead, but I think you would still get the cross-threading error.

Your simplest fix would be to move the code that creates and shows the second form out of your class and into `ParentForm`. So instead of this:

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.ShowDialog(ParentForm);
```

you would do this:

```
ParentForm.showMyNewForm();
```

and in `ParentForm` you would have this:

```
public void showMyNewForm()
{
    MyForm form = new MyForm();
    form.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

If `MyForm` needs to have a reference to the class on the other thread, you would just add a parameter to `showMyNewForm()` so that the reference to it can be passed in.

What you're trying to do here (creating and showing related, connected forms that are created on different threads) is really going against the grain of how forms are meant to be used in .NET.

Comment: Thanks although I feel what I'm doing is pretty straightforward and not really going against .Net. I have a form which has a button,when clicked it starts a new thread and runs a long running task. This gives the user the ability to still the use GUI but also allows them to cancel the thread. The issue is, if there is a problem in the thread I need some user input by displaying a new form, but it appears in the background. Not sure how I could resolve this by putting the form call onto the parent form

Comment: Well, all of the forms in a .NET app should be created on the same thread, or else you run into weirdness like what you're seeing. If you display the new form from your parent form as I suggested, you can still reference your long-running task thread from this new form.

Comment: How do I call the showMyNewForm from my separate class on a different thread and test its ModalResult?

Comment: Change `showMyNewForm()` so that it returns whatever info you're collecting from the dialog (make the return type `string` or whatever you need) and then Invoke showMyNewForm(), using the same kind of syntax as in your sample method. Conceptually, you're then letting ParentForm handle the job of collecting this info from the user, and your long-task thread doesn't (and shouldn't) know anything about how this is done.

Comment: Sorry to wake up a thread from long ago. What if the dialog I'm creating should actually be incapsulated in my long-running operation? The operation may be called from many places: your solution seems to suggest I should replicate the code to create the dialog every time I launch the operation from a new place?

Answer (score 0):

you can add async method to a form. 
Let's say like this:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public void ShowModalAsync()
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(()=> {
              ShowDilaog(..);
        }));  
    }
}
```

and use this, like:

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.ShowModalAsync(...);
```

*Should* work for you.

By the way, if your problem is **only** the fact that the window appears on bihind of others, try to make use of [Form.TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx) property setting it to `true`. Having in mind that it, yes, will bring it infront of other forms, but not necessary infront of other topmost forms.

Comment: The issue is it being behind. TopMost is set to true but it still hides behind. I thought adding in the ParentForm would work but I need to call it from another thread as well

Comment: @Jon: if TopMost is True, it *seems* to me that you have *other* topmost forms running in the same moment, but created *before* that one. Is this true?

Comment: I dont think the parent is topmost but the grandparent may be